# Prediction using random-forest model in python

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, classification, random-forest

I have this [three column dataset](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4Ajk8jGD1OxSEl2cnF6TC1lUXM) formatted as in the following

```
t_stamp,Xval,Ytval
0.000543,0,10
0.000575,0,10
0.041324,1,10
0.041331,2,10
0.041336,3,10
0.04134,4,10
0.041345,5,10
0.04135,6,10
0.041354,7,10
```

How can we predict the current value of `Y` (the true value) using the last 5 data points of `Xval` using `random forest classifier model` of `sklearn` in `Python`? Meaning taking `[0,0,1,2,3]` of `Xval` column as an input - i want to predict the 5th row value of `Ytval`. Using a simple `rolling OLS regression model`, we can do it as in the following but I wanted to do it using `random forest model`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data_pred.csv')
model = pd.stats.ols.MovingOLS(y=df.Ytval, x=df[['Xval']], 
                               window_type='rolling', window=5, intercept=True)
```

Comment: This question seems to be not specific to Random Forests, but rather about data transformation. You might consider changing your title.

Comment: I removed the flag from the other question but it seems that a moderator removed the question.

Comment: @sera, I removed it myself to extend the question more.

Answer (score 1):

You can realize the rolling input data on your own by reforming your data so that each of the last 5 values of X becomes it's own feature:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

data = StringIO("""t_stamp,Xval,Ytval
0.000543,0,10
0.000575,0,10
0.041324,1,10
0.041331,2,10
0.041336,3,10
0.04134,4,10
0.041345,5,10
0.04135,6,10
0.041354,7,10""")

df = pd.read_csv(data)

for i in range(1,6):
    df['Xval_t'+str(i)] = df['Xval'].shift(i)
```

Which yields `df`:

```
t_stamp    Xval Ytval   Xval_t1 Xval_t2 Xval_t3 Xval_t4 Xval_t5
0.000543    0   10      NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
0.000575    0   10      0.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
0.041324    1   10      0.0     0.0     NaN     NaN     NaN
0.041331    2   10      1.0     0.0     0.0     NaN     NaN
0.041336    3   10      2.0     1.0     0.0     0.0     NaN
0.041340    4   10      3.0     2.0     1.0     0.0     0.0
0.041345    5   10      4.0     3.0     2.0     1.0     0.0
0.041350    6   10      5.0     4.0     3.0     2.0     1.0
0.041354    7   10      6.0     5.0     4.0     3.0     2.0
```

Of course, you need to decide on how to handle the `NaNs`. I just drop them for demonstration purposes.

```
df.dropna(inplace=True)

X = df[['Xval', 'Xval_t1', 'Xval_t2', 'Xval_t3', 'Xval_t4', 'Xval_t5']].values
y = df['Ytval'].values

reg = RandomForestRegressor()
reg.fit(X,y)
print(reg.predict(X))
```

Result:

```
[ 10.  10.  10.  10.]
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I want to drop the `NaNs` like you did. Is it possible to use `randomforestclassifier` instead of `randomforestregressor` and  include `RMSE` at the end?

Comment: You can fit a classifier exactly the same way. Just import `RandomForestClassifier` instead. But are you sure that classification makes sense with your data? What is the range of possible values for Y? Furthermore, RMSE is a metric for regression algorithms, it has no place in a classification problem. Suitable metrics for classification include e.g. Accuracy, Precision, ROC-AUC,...

Comment: `RMSE` does not depend on the learning algorithm used before it. It simply calculates a metric dependent on two input vectors. See http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#model-evaluation for details on how to apply an arbitrary metric function in `sklearn`.